# mysql: remove text from column that is contained in another column

Tags: mysql

So ihave a database that contains address, city, state, and zipcode columns. The problem is the address column includes the address as well as the city, state, and zip. As these are already columns, i dont want them in the address column. Is there a way to dynamically remove the data from the address column that matches city, state, and zip? The database has over 50,000 rows.

Comment: You want to do this is table? whats your condition to delete? Explain in detail.

Comment: Is the format of the address consistent throughout the database? I.E. is it always `address, city, state zip`?

Comment: Your biggest problem here is going to be variability of the content. If your data is anything like other DBs I've seen, then most likely some addresses contain the rogue data, and others don't, and others contain some of it but not all. Plus it may sometimes be comma-separated, sometimes not, and sometimes the data in the address field doesn't match the separate fields. My advice is to be very careful with what you do, because what you're proposing is potentially destructive; it's probably better to have it as it is than to lose some of the data entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), but messy to do: try this at the MySQL console:

```
mysql> create table `m2` (`id` int(11) auto_increment, a TEXT, b TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into `m2` (a, b) VALUES ('200 Honolulu Drive Los Angeles CA 89999','89999');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from m2;
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------+
| id | a                                       | b     |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | 200 Honolulu Drive Los Angeles CA 89999 | 89999 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update `m2` set a = TRIM(REPLACE(a, b,'')) WHERE id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from m2;
+----+-----------------------------------+-------+
| id | a                                 | b     |
+----+-----------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | 200 Honolulu Drive Los Angeles CA | 89999 |
+----+-----------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If your formats aren't VERY regular (or you have the zip code, state or city value that occurs in multiple places in the address field) you could easily damage your address field so I'd recommend you do it with code, rather than SQL.

But it is there for you, in a pinch.